# Scala how to sort the "None" to bottom if exist and select first row in each group?

Tags: java, scala, sorting, apache-spark, group-by

I am grouping by the first element which results in `RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, String, Option[Node])])]`.

I would like to sort by the `Option[Node]` if it has `None` the `None` should be sorted to bottom in each group and select the first row for each group.

```
I have 

[(x,compactBuffer((x,y,z),(x,y,None),(x,y,p))],
[(a,compactBuffer((a,b,c),(a,b,d))],
[(s,compactBuffer((s,t,None),(s,t,None),(s,t,u))],
[(l,compactBuffer((l,m,None)]
```

Expected output

```
[(x,compactBuffer((x,y,z))],
[(a,compactBuffer((a,b,c))],
[(s,compactBuffer((s,t,u))], // select (s,t,u) since the first two rows 
have None
[(l,compactBuffer((l,m,None)]
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you have implementing it?

Comment: Should not the first output element be `[(x, compactBuffer((x, y, p)))]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly try appending mapValue after your groupBy:

```
rdd.groupBy([Your Key]).mapValues(_.sortBy(_._3).reverse.take(1)).values
```

Even though it is said that you can not compare two options, but the above code works for me..., or else you can create a conversion of `A : Ordering => Ordered[A]`, then your options could be compared directly.